# Timeout command in batch

Tags: batch-file, timeout, escaping

I want to create a batch file with a timer in it, using another batch file. In the first one I wrote

```
type NUL > File2.bat

echo Timeout /T 5 /NOBREAK>NUL>> "File1.bat"
```

A batch file called File1.bat is made, but the "`> NUL`" is missing. It only contains.

```
Timeout /T 5 /NOBREAK
```

Can someone please assist me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert a caret character (`^`) before the `>`. This "escapes" the special meaning of the `>`.

Best to use a *text editor* to create batch files. I use *editplus* ut there are many others, including `notepad++`.

Don't use a word-processor, and be very careful if you use `notepad` (as supplied with windows) as these are aimed more at word-processing and automatically format the file created as a document rather than a simple text file.

Comment: `Notepad` isn't able to format anything. Did you think of `Wordpad` (`write.exe`)?

Comment: @Stephan : `wordpad` I've not used in years. `Notepad` is often the source of errors posted on SO as it plays games - save in unicode, drop required end-of-line spaces and a few other things - perhaps word-wrap which confuses `cmd`. I really can't recall the precise details - very rarely use it in consequence of the little games it plays. Or maybe I'm getting confused - I still recommend using a 3rd-party editor.